# Elements in Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm pretty new to RE. What is the difference between "*" and "+"? They all seem to indicate equal the preceding element zero or more times, as much as possible?

Comment: `help('re')`  That gives you a lot of information including that.

Answer (score 0):

`+` means **one** or more times, while `*` is **zero** or more times

> "*" Causes the resulting RE to match **0** or more repetitions of the
> preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. ab* will match ‘a’,
> ‘ab’, or ‘a’ followed by any number of ‘b’s.
>
> '+' Causes the resulting
> RE to match **1** or more repetitions of the preceding RE. ab+ will match
> ‘a’ followed by any non-zero number of ‘b’s; it will not match just
> ‘a’.

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 0):

`*` matches 0 or more times. It is successful even if there is no match. So `a*` will be successful even in the string `bcd`

`+` matches 1 or more times. There should be at least one match, then only its successful. If we use `a+`, then there should be at least one `a` present for successful match. So it will fail for the string `bcd`

Both of `*` and `+` are greedy in nature so they will match as much as possible before `terminating or backtracking`

Answer (score 0):

- The `+` quantifier selects the preceding character `1` or more times, as many times as possible
- The `*` quantifier selects the preceding character `0` or more times, as many times as possible

Examples

Using the RegEx [`foo\d+bar`](https://regex101.com/r/tP5kN5/1) (with a `+`):

```
foo1bar     # Match
foo234bar   # Match
foobar      # Not a Match
```

[image: Using <code>+</code>]

Using the RegEx [`foo\d*bar`](https://regex101.com/r/xM5eI9/1) (with a `*`):

```
foo1bar     # Match
foo234bar   # Match
foobar      # Match
```

[image: Using <code>*</code>]

---

A quote from the [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html) on `re`:

> - `+` - Causes the resulting RE to match **`1`** or more repetitions of the preceding RE. `ab+` will match `a` followed by any non-zero number of `b`s; it **will not match just `a`**
> - `*` - Causes the resulting RE to match **`0`** or more repetitions of the preceding RE, as many repetitions as are possible. `ab*` will match `a`, `ab`, or `a` **followed by any number of `b`s**